# Mod_rewrite not redirecting properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

first of all I know there are questions about my problem I tried few of them, but unsuccessfully.
I am trying to get:

```
http://example.com/project/text
```

from

```
http://example.com/projects.php?c=text
```

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ projects.php?c=$1 [L,QSA] 
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

When I open the site i.e. http://example.com/project/123456 I get nothing(Blank site).
Thank you for you help.

Comment: Did you try adding the `RewriteBase /` to your htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I tried but still it doesn't work

Comment: And of course you confirmed putting the regular link in the browser works?

Comment: yes when I add http://example.com/projects.php?c123456 it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^project/(.+)$ projects.php?c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Check you Apache error.log and open your page in Firebug to see what status are you getting.

Comment: In my error.log is nothing about htaccess or about mod_rewrite

Comment: I also wrote about Firebug. What status do you see there?

Comment: Here is the Net tab from Firebug https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnx2yvh23bnm0rh/firebug.png  Sorry for late

Comment: But this image isn;t showing any request for `/project/123456` URI. Also let me know in which directory you have kept .htaccess file?

Comment: The projects.php and .htacces are in the same folder(www/)

Comment: OK Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: No, it isn't. I changed "project" in     .htaccess to "p" and it's the same problem.

Comment: ok try this rule: `RewriteRule ^project/(.+)$ projects.php?c=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]`

Comment: Now, when I write to the URL http://example.com/123456 it's redirecting to the http://example.com/projects.php?c=123456

Comment: ok that means rule is right as redirect is happening but internal rewrite is not happening.

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo();?>` Then try this rule: `RewriteRule ^project/(.+)$ info.php?c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: OK that's fantastic. That explains there is some code inside `projects.php` which is causing 404 since rule worked with `info.php`